# Jquery scroll to div wether you are above or below div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple snippet of Jquery to scroll the user to a particular div (`.target`) on clicking (`.click`). This works fine when the user is above `.target`, but does not work if they are below `.target`. Is it possible to make this work in both directions?

```
$(".click").on('click', function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(".target").offset().top;
    }, 1000); });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

its working. you have syntax error

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("table").offset().top
  }, 1000)
});
```

```css
table { margin: 700px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>click</button>
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>click</button>
```